# QGIS Statistic only for intersected areas

Tags: qgis, statistics

I would like to derive statistics (especially "mean") from a column of a layer, but only for those areas, that intersect with polygones of another layer.
Is there an expression that can derive this statistics? Or do I first have to create a new layer by intersecting, and then deriving basic statistics from it? (which would be cumbersome as I want to do this for different intersections/layers)

Comment: If you have to split polygons and recalculate area or proportional stats, you will have to run an overlay like intersect.  In QGIS running an intersect produces a temporary layer and thus is pretty easy with no cleanup mess if you don't save the results.  If you don't need to split polygons you could run the Processing select by location tool, even doing a batch selection and then in the vector analysis box get statistics of the selected features or copy the selection attributes for use in a spreadsheet.

Comment: Can you be more specific? For example, are the statistics across the entire layer, or are the statistics grouped by some attribute. Maybe include a diagram or image.